# Limit of $f'(x) e^{-f(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a real function verifying $f''\geq C>0$, where C is a constant.

 Do we have : $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x) e^{-f(x)}=0$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you add some more context? Is this homework or a problem you found by yourself? What did you try?

Comment: No it's not a homework, it's a question from a friend (to which he couldn't find a solution), from $f''\geq C>0$, I can only show that  $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ and I get an indeterminate form..

Comment: It is easy to see that if the desired limit exists then it will be zero. The difficult part is to figure out if the limit exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: transform the limit to an indeterminate form such as $[\frac{0}{0}]$ or $[\frac{\infty}{\infty}]$, and apply *De L'Hopital's Rule*:
as you mentioned in a comment $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, so $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x) e^{-f(x)}$ would be an indeterminate form such as $+\infty\cdot0$. You'd better to turn the limit in order to use *De L'Hopital's Theorem*:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x) e^{-f(x)}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^{-f(x)}}{\frac{1}{f'(x)}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{-f'(x)e^{-f(x)}}{\frac{-f''(x)}{f'(x)^2}}=...$$

Comment: Thank you, but $\frac{f'(x)^3}{c e^{f(x)}}$ doesn't seem to have a limit..
We can also use $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)e^{f(x)}} \geq \frac{C}{f'(x)e^{f(x)}} \geq 0$ but I still can't show that the limit exists..